# Getting the correct macaddress in Java 7

Tags: java, networking, mac-address

Tried to use the getHardwareAddress() method to get the mac address of my network card, however according to NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() I have over 20 network interfaces. Ive narrowed it down to one by checking other attributes, but is this going to work in all (or at least most cirumstances) and operating systems, only tried on a WIndows 7 PC.

And if a computer has two network cards, can I find out which one is actually being used for a current internet connection ?

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(e.hasMoreElements())
{
   NetworkInterface ni = e.nextElement();
   if(ni!=null && ni.getHardwareAddress()!=null &&ni.getInetAddresses().hasMoreElements() && ni.supportsMulticast())
   {
      String macAddress   = Hex.encodeHexString(ni.getHardwareAddress());
      System.out.println("MACADDRESSIS"+macAddress);
   }
}
```

Comment: MAC address can be changed so easily, I hope you don't rely too much on it for security

Comment: All the MAC addresses are potentially used.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey On Windows ipconfig clearly shows the proper mac address, so Im just asking how to do that in pure Java way

Comment: On Windows `ipconfig /all` shows you all the MAC Addresses and in Java it should do the same. On my Windows 7 it shows the same MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an InetAddress, you can get the current NetworkInterface using [`NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getByInetAddress%28java.net.InetAddress%29).

Comment: I dont know the inet address either, but maybe I can get the current ipaddress and then get hardware address from it ?